# Оформление диалогов (когда слова автора представляют собой отдельное предложение?)

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Я знаю о правиле: "Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы".

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Но часто встречаю такие предложения:

— Ясновидящая, что ли? — ухмыляется Юджин.

— Ладно, — отмахнулся он.

Это же не глаголы речи, но они все же относятся к прямой речи. Писать ли их с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом примере *ухмыляется* и *отмахнулся* воспринимаются как слова, вводящие прямую речь. Как указывает Розенталь [(§ 48](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=156#pp156)), такие слова допускают добавление к ним глаголов речи (ухмыляется и говорит, отмахнулся и сказал). Поэтому авторские слова **не** представляют собой предложение, отдельное от прямой речи.